# Content types - custom view

Tags: views, theming

I know there is option to preview content type after save. But i want to customise that preview by my css..i want to use image i upload to content type as background and put text on it from content as well. I am learning about modules/themes but i dont know the right way to do this. Opinion of someone experienced would be nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tokens and custom CSS in the view.  Takes a little fiddling to get it perfect, because Drupal throws in a bit of it's XHTML.